# Can I use my mtgox BTC balance on the mtgox checkout button/payment platform while my account is pending verification?

Tags: mtgox

Can I use my mtgox BTC balance on the mtgox checkout button/payment platform while my account is pending verification ? Like purchase goods and services from people who use the mtgox merchant tools to accept BTC on their sites.

Comment: Did Mt. Gox initiate the verification or did you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, verification is only for increasing the amount of BTC and other currency you can move

```
"up to 10x your current daily limit, and up to 5x your current monthly limit"
```

through their service. It also enables you to use other services with mtgox such as [dwolla](https://www.dwolla.com/).

Comment: So do you mean *eventually* we can use all our BTC even without verification?

Comment: yep, just if you have a lot it may take some time